# Trying to save an argument as a variable in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I am trying to save the argument after "-ip" as a variable in the bash script:

```
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
        ARGS=""
else
        for var in "$@"
        do
                ARGS="$ARGS $var"
                if [ $var == "-ip" ];   then
                        getopts ip: $IP
                fi
        done
fi

echo $IP
```

I never tried 'getopts' in bash, I tried the first time as you can see above and failed literally.

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reading the description of `getopts` in `man bash` or `help getopts`?

Comment: There are tons of examples here. Keep searching.

Comment: Notice that `getopts` supports only single-letter options.

Comment: since getopts only supports single-letter options, would someone have any other options on this bash script? thanks !

Comment: Don't collect the arguments in a regular parameter like `ARGS`. If `ARGS` contains `foo bar`, you can't tell if that was one single argument `foo bar` or two separate arguments `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: See: [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid getopts all together and just grab it with a regex.

```
myvar=$(echo "$@" | sed 's/.*-ip\s\+\([0-9a-zA-Z\.]\+\)\s*.*/\1/g')
```

Loads whatever is after -ip into myvar.  Adjust the regex accordingly if you only want something that will match an IP.

Comment: I would *not* recommend using this -- it mashes all the arguments into a single string, and looks for "`-ip `" anywhere in it. But that could be in the middle of an argument (spaces are legal -- and even normal -- in arguments), at the end of an argument (say you have a file named "servers-by-ip" -- this'll mistake the "-ip" part for a flag).